# Facebook SDK: Ads Install Help on Xamarin.iOS

Tags: facebook, sdk, xamarin.ios, installation, ads

has anyone used the FBSettings.PublishInstall(APP_ID) api method from the Facebook SDK in Xamarin.iOS with success ?

I've read and applied all the stuff described here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/mobile-app-ads/

but I'm unable to see any install notification on my FB developer application page.

Some questions:
- Is this testable in debug mode via a REAL device? (no emulator)
- To test if all is ok, do I need to create a campaign?
- There's a way to check if the method call FBSettings.PublishInstall() throw some error? I'm currently wrapping it in a try/catch block but nothing is thrown.

thanks
Francesco

Answer (score 0):

I've finally sorted out the whole thing. I'm auto answering my question just in case anyone in future needs some help.

How to test Facebook Ads Install step by step:

As reference guide read this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/mobile-app-ads/

- Create a FB app and obtain a FB AppID (namespace is not required)
- Fill iOS and Android store references data
- Inlude the FB Sdk binding in your project
- Execute the FBSettings.PublishInstall(APP_ID) in the OnActivated (for iOS) or in the OnResume (for Android) methods

Test this with an AdHoc release on a REAL device (don't know if it works with a debug release)

Very Important: the official FB app must be installed on the test device. Install notifications are sent ONLY if the FB app is installed and running (logged with a valid account) !!!!!!!